# Electron - не работает require в iframe

Tags: javascript, electron

При использовании `require` в `<iframe src"path/to/frame.html"></iframe>` который расположен в основном файле index.html, получаю ошибку `require is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы node модулей необходимо использовать тег 
`<webview src="path/to/frame.html" nodeintegration><webview>`, а не `<iframe src="path/to/frame.html"></iframe>`